# How CSV will accept german umlaute as well as english in c#

Tags: c#, csv, entity-framework-6

I am facing problem to import CSV file if the file contains german umlauts. I had tried following code.

```
public TablePreviewDto ProcessCsv(CsvFileDto csvFileDto)
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(csvFileDto.EncodedString.Replace("data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,", ""));
            string fileContent;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(csvFileDto.EncodingName))
            {
                fileContent = Encoding.GetEncoding(csvFileDto.EncodingName).GetString(data);
            }
            else
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(data), true);
                fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return ProcessCsvContent(csvFileDto, fileContent);
        }
```

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Can you tell what is the problem.

Comment: I am getting an error: Invalid content found in one or more cells of the Excel file (.csv). A file contains some german umlauts. For pure English, it works fine.

Comment: Can you add the portion of (sanitized for confidential data) csv with the question.

Comment: Row1Column1 = name;username;email;password, Row2Column2 = John Göhina;jgöhina;jgöhina@yahoo.com;Aa$$# is excel content.